# is 300ms click delay back for ios 10?

Tags: ios, zooming

Consider the following snippet that should  prevent zooming in and out on mobile devices

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

For ios 10 it no longer prevents zoom because of accessibility issues. So is the 300ms delay before firing click event back  for ios 10? I check it for my  website and it doesn't feel like there is performance downgrade. or is there?

Has Apple found a work around for this issue?

Comment: I just discovered the same thing and came here to see if there was a solution. Welp. Looks like this meta tag is of no use anymore (unless Android is still using these parameters).